# Why does node.js "injects" 3 DIVs at the bottom of each HTML rendered to the browser?

Tags: node.js, express

I see that in my node.js apps, all html files generated back to the browser have 3 strange DIVs:

```
<div id="hrUEoB6QvVpGs3Es" class="qlg5qGErCB54seZV66a0vA2ej" style="display: none;"></div>
<div id="_F_hxffOOh_6ZHFIeMDRoqsm4" class="qlg5qGErCB54seZV66a0vA2ej" style="display: none;"></div>
<div id="JMqGBWD8CJFbQCArt25" class="qlg5qGErCB54seZV66a0vA2ej" style="display: none;"></div>
```

any idea why?

Comment: What rendering engine are you using?

Comment: Are you using any `<script>` libraries that could be injecting them?

Comment: Is this in all browsers? I'd check it with `curl` and see if you still have these elements. I've seen some chrome/FF extension "inject" garbage like this.

Answer (score 1):

Neither Node nor Jade inject anything like that by themselves. You should check your middleware and .jade templates.